# TFS 2013, only partial success on builds. "An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location"

Tags: continuous-integration, build-server

I know this problem has been reported quite a few times, but the solutions I've found didn't work for me. The setup:

1. We performed an upgrade of TFS 2010 to TFS2013 As described in one
   of the upgrade manuals we have backed up the databases and analysis
   services key and restored them on a different box. Let's call this
   new box **boxTFS2013**. Initially the entire setup was done there
   and, some sharepoint problems aside, it was successful. But the
   build services started reporting this problem:

   > **"An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: The HTTP request timed out after
   >   00:01:40."**

   Pretty much everything associated with TFS, including the build
   service runs on the account **DOMAIN\TFSService**. Nothing is on
   **NTNetworkAuthority**
2. As a second step we created a new build server, **boxBUILD2013**, installed the build services there and uninstalled the build
   services from **boxTFS2013**. Again the very same problem - the
   builds succeed partially and the same log copy failure occurs.

**The setup now is as follows:**

The TFS2013, SQL and Sharepoint is on the **boxTFS2013** (Sharepoint is about to be moved). TFS2013 is running on the **DOMAIN\TFSService account**.

Build services are set up on **boxBUILD2013**. There is one controller and two agents. The working folder for the agents is d:\BUILD, the account is **DOMAIN\TFSService**.
The drop folder is on the same box, e:\BUILDS (name about to be changed after we resolve our current problems).

Normally people resolve this problem by giving the build agent rights to write to the drop folder. This was so from the very beginning (that domain account always had access) but the problem persists. Just to verify that the problem is not associated with permissions I have given the account Everyone full control rights over: d:\BUILD and e:\Builds

The xml build definition, as far as I can tell, does not contain anything out of ordinary. The builds drop the files where they are supposed to, the partial failure only occurs on the log. I'm out of ideas really. Can anyone advise, please?

Answer (score 4):

Solution: 
Increae the timeout within  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools\TFSBuildServiceHost.exe.config
by adding

```
<appSettings> 
<add key="ServerDrop.MaxRequestTimeInSeconds" value="300"/>
</appSettings>
```

Herbert

Answer (score 0):

To some extent I managed to resolve it.

Apparently the Build Server does some HTTP Post to the TFS server after the successful build. Absolutely no idea why or what it is. This fails if TFS Server is busy for some reason. It may be an obstructed network, it may be something else. In our case it was underpowered box the TFS runs on. Adding 4GB RAM to that box (the TFS one, NOT the build one!) solved this problem. So basically the Build server was failing and throwing errors because the TFS server didn't have enough RAM. We are still having a lot of problems with the SQL throwing bucketloads of error logs in spite of being on a really strong box now, but I'm hopeful we'll be able to resolve this.